# How to disable DirectoryIndexRedirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am migrating/rehosting a site which has lots of files in directories such as `/doc/year/17` and it relied on Apache's creating directory listings of those files. In my new site I have a PHP file in the top level to handle the directory listing and I use a rewrite rule as follows:

`RewriteRule ^doc/year/([0-9][0-9])/?$ year.php?y=$1 [L,NC]`

This works, but because (in the example above), /doc/year/17 exists, Apache creates a 301 redirect to `/doc/year/17?y=17`. I don't want the redirect and I especially don't want a 301 redirect.

I have tried:

`DirectoryIndexRedirect Off
DirectoryCheckHandler Off
RewriteOptions AllowNoSlash`

which, according to the Apache documentation, should do the trick, but none of these do. I verified that if the directory doesn't exist, then I don't get the redirect. I can think of complicated ways of handling this, but it seems that I should just be able to stop Apache from creating the redirect. What am I missing?

For context, here is my entire .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
DirectoryIndexRedirect Off
DirectoryCheckHandler Off
RewriteOptions AllowNoSlash
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /403.php

RewriteRule ^doc/meeting/([0-9]+[A-Z]?)(.*)$ meeting.php?m=$1&f=$2 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^doc/year/?$ year.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^doc/year/([0-9][0-9])/?$ year.php?y=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^doc/meeting/?$ meeting.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^doc/standing/?$ standing.php [L,NC]
```

(Removing -indexes doesn't change things.)

Comment: `DirectoryIndexRedirect` and `DirectoryCheckHandler` are already   **Off**  on Apache by default so You don't need these lines. Do you have any other rules that can  conflict with this one?

Comment: I showed you my entire .htaccess.

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache.

Comment: No difference - still get the redirect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like what may be happening is [mod_dir](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash) is attempting to redirect to the same directory but with a trailing slash. There is a **really good reason** why it does this by default:

> Security Warning
>
> Turning off the trailing slash redirect may result in an information disclosure. Consider a situation where `mod_autoindex` is active (`Options +Indexes`) and `DirectoryIndex` is set to a valid resource (say, `index.html`) and there's no other special handler defined for that URL. In this case a request with a trailing slash would show the `index.html` file. **But a request without trailing slash would list the directory contents.**

Eventhough you have the indexes option turned off, the `DirectorySlash` directive is still doing the redirecting. So you can try turning it off but adding a rule at the very end of your list of rules that does the same thing:

So add this somewhere near the top:

```
DirectorySlash Off
```

then this at the end of your rules (or something similar, you may need to tweak depending on your folder structure):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R]
```

Just make sure you keep in mind that directory slash is turned off.

Comment: How did I miss DirectorySlash when I was reading the mod_dir documentation! Thanks, this works. I had seen the warning and it doesn't apply to my site.